# jquery date picker with table input elements

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, html-table, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created an html table and am binding JQuery date picker elements to 3 of the input fields. However, only one of the date pickers get bound. The other two do not get bound. I am unable to understand the error!! A snippet of HTML code and script is as below.

```
<table class="passenger-list">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>D-O-B</td>
        <td>Passport #</td>
        <td>Expiry Date</td>
        <td>Destination</td>
        <td>Departure Date</td>
        <td>Arrival Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="DOB" />
        </td>
                <td>
            <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="PassNum" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="PassExpiry" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Destination" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="ArrDate" id = "ArrDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="DepDate" id="DepDate"/>
        </td>
        <td><a class="remove">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-passenger">Add Passenger</a>
```

and the script for Jquery is as follows. ArrDate works fine but the other two do not.

```
<script>
$("#DOB").datepicker({
        minDate: "-70Y",
        maxDate: "-18Y",
        numberOfMonths: 1
        }
    });
</script>

<script>
$("#ArrDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#DepDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

 $("#DepDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#ArrDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });

 </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: For DOB, there's an extra curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

Roamer-1888 has answered(in comment) your question. i also checked it.

here is jsfiddle of that answer
[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/128/)
    `

```
<script>
 $(function(){

$('#DOB').datepicker({
    minDate: "-70Y",
    maxDate: "-18Y",
    numberOfMonths: 1
});

$("#ArrDate").datepicker({ 
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate:"+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#ArrDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
    }}
);

    $("#DepDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#DepDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
    }
});
});
</script>
```